# Allow flex items to keep fixed width and scroll horizontally inside container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent that's using `display: flex;`. It has four children (cards) currently, but it may have more. All the children need big, but equal, widths.
For example, each child needs a `40%` width. If that happens, only a certain amount of children will fit on the screen. I need to be able to do that, and have the rest of the children be accessible with horizontal scrolling.

[image: explanation image]

How do I achieve this? I tried using `flex-wrap: no-wrap;` and then increasing the width of the children, but the parent doesn't allow that. This seems intentional, but I basically want to override this behaviour.

HTML

```
 <div id="parent">
   <div class="children">
       <card-header>
           <b class="text"">Text</b>
       </card-header>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row no-wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.children {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you're searching for the CSS `overflow` property.

Try adding `overflow-x: auto` to the container.

And make the children less flexible.

Instead of this:

```
width: 50%;
```

Try this:

```
flex: 0 0 50%; /* don't grow, don't shrink, stay fixed at 50% width */
```

The initial value of `flex-shrink` is `1`, which means the flex item will shrink to avoid overflowing the container. With the code above we override the default with `0`, which essentially turns off flex shrink.